# Calling method indefinitely

Tags: c#, wpf, c++-cli

I want to use a .dll created with c++/cli that includes normal c code in an c# wpf project.
A function of the c code needs permanent calling. This function was orginally called in an endless loop in the main function of a c command-line-application.

How do I call a function permanently from a wpf c# project without interfering with the rest of the application? I guess that should be pretty easy but Im new to wpf and fairly new to .Net.

Comment: What does "permanent calling" mean?

Comment: In embedded programming we call functions Perm-Functions that are called every 5 or 10 milliseconds (permanently). I don´t get what calling method "indefinitely" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Threading;

Thread t = new Thread(()=>{
while(true)
{
//call your method here...
Thread.Sleep(500); //optional if you want a pause between calls.
}
});
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `while(true)` loop on another [thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, all you want to do is keep calling the method? Use a timer:

Include `using System.Windows.Threading;` at the top of the file. Then write:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(x); //x is the amount of milliseconds you want between each method call

timer.Tick += (source, e) =>
{
    method();
};
timer.Start();
```

The timer will run your method with every tick, and you can write additional code in the anonymous method to control how often/how many times your method is called, when it is called, and so on. And of course, it won't interfere with the rest of your program.

If you want to call your program as often as possible, replace x in the second line with 1.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. Using another Thread might have also worked but I rather stick to one thread to avoid multithreading issues.

Comment: @user1550097: You do realize that timers usually are also creating new threads, right?